# Find all except id's in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array with ID's I've collected from my clients.

Now I'd like to get all of the records from my `Activityclient` table **except** the ones I have in my `collectedClients` array.

I haven't really tried anything because I have no clue on how to approach this, ha!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rails 4, you can use `where.not` to do this:

```
collectedClients = [1,5,9]
Activityclient.where.not(id: collectedClients)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Activityclient.where(["id NOT IN (?)", collectedClients])
```